# redis set the same key, performance problems?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

set the same key ,poor performance?

I'm doing a stress test, using the same seeionid.

I found that when I set the same key, the performance was poor.
If the keys are different, the performance is good.

Is there a problem with the way I use it? Can it be improved?

```
idatabase.StringSet("SESSION:" + sessionid+":USER_ID",
                                     userid, new TimeSpan(24,0,0));
```

My web application uses redis to manage session (aspx).

If it is a new member, insert session and set a 24-hour expiration date.
Otherwise, the update expiration time is 24 hours.

Comment: Define `poor` and `good` for us.  It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry,  set the same key  , the performance is very low.

Comment: Do you reuse the same ConnectionMultiplexer instance on c#? Do you connect to a cluster or a single-server Redis?